# Empty Repeater Slots and Percent FM when downloading D-STAR repeater list

Tags: repeater, d-star, radio-programming

When downloading a repeater list from [dstarinfo.com](http://www.dstarinfo.com/RepeaterDownloads.aspx) as shown in [this video:
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJCvLsK1cKc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJCvLsK1cKc), there are two numeric fields:

- Empty Repeater Slots
- Percent FM

What are they? What do they mean?

[image: Screenshot of form]

Answer (score 1):

The empty repeater slots are the remaining memories in available in your radio. The Percent FM are the number of repeaters in the list that are standard FM (i.e. not DV).

Comment: How does it chose which repeaters not to include when you vary the Percent FM? Is there a way of just getting *all* repeaters?